# Inserting and reading data within a database

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlite

Basically im trying to insert data into a database and then reading that data elsewhere and inserting each individual piece into a entry field.

Firstly this is the page in which the data i will want inserted into the database from the [Statistics page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUD0Y.png)

From this page i will want the Occupation,Monthly Rental,Estimated Property Value to all be stored in the database called "PropertyStatistics" [which is showed here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvDHk.png)

After being saved i want the stored value to be outputted to entry boxed so it's visible

**Current Code**
The code i have for inserting the data into the database:

```
def data_entry():
        OccupationA = str(Statusvar.get())
        MonthlyRentalA = RentalmoneyUpdated
        EstimatedPropertyValueA = EstimatedValueentry
        PropertyStatisticsR = c.fetchall()
        for column in PropertyStatisticsR:
            ID = column[1]
            OccupationA = column[2]
            MonthlyRentalA = column[3]
            EstimatedPropertyValueA = column[4]


            c.execute("INSERT INTO PropertyStatistics(ID,Occupation,Monthly Rental,Estimated Property Value) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
            (ID,OccupationA,MonthlyRentalA,EstimatedPropertyValueA))


            conn.commit()
            time.sleep(1)
```

The function "data_entry" is called by a "save" button as shown in link1
currently for this code no error's show up on executing this function however nothing is saved to the database which means i''ve overlooked a error

I'm a beginner and any help would be appreciated as i haven't done this sort of thing before.

I don't expect a reply to contain all the code required for this to work. I just need a little direction in where to go from where i am now

Answer (score 2):

For multi-word column name, when referring, they should be enclosed in ``.

```
INSERT INTO PropertyStatistics(ID,Occupation,`Monthly Rental`,`Estimated Property Value`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)
```